# hp pavillion elite not booting beep codes

Tags: boot, memory, desktop, hp-pavilion

I'm trying to fix a hp pavillion elite. It won't boot, can't even get to the bios screen. I get one short beep, one long beep, and the screen never even turns on. Beep codes online say it's memory related, but it's got 4 sticks of 2gb in it, and I've tried swapping them all out, using one at a time, etc, they seem to be fine, and were all working before the owner tried to plug in an additional hard drive, which is when the problems started. He tried pulling everything out, putting it back in again, and this is the condition I've got it in. I tried removing every plug-able piece inside it- stripped down to the original hard drive and any one of the sticks of ram, still just the 2 beeps.  Tried pulling the motherboard battery to reset everything, still nothing. I can't find anything online about jumper settings for the motherboard, or any additional help, but I'd really rather not just hand it back to him and tell him to send it to HP and spend the $200 plus any parts... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A) If you pull ALL the RAM out does it give the same beeps?
B) If you use different, *known-good* RAM does it still beep the same way?
C) Have you tried a different, known-good PSU yet?

If A and B and C, and it still acts the same way, then you have a fried motherboard.

Comment: A and B: check.
c) haven't tried a new power supply, but just like all the other pieces, it was functioning correctly up until the pc was disassembled... and everything seems to power up fine, and the pc is pretty new... 
If this is correct, it matches what others have said, which is that the motherboard was probably damaged during all the initial toying... :/
if that's the case, am I better off telling him to send it back to HP? or try and wire him up a new one?

Comment: if it's under warranty send it to HP, otherwise who fixes it is up to you and the customer. :)